# Deploy Ruby on Rails app with railway.app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, redis, sidekiq, puma

I'm trying to deploy my app on railway.app with Redis (using Sidekiq).
I'm using buildpacks and the problem is I have 2 buildpacks and railway says in its documentation only one buildpack is executed in the Procfile.
This is my Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
worker: bundle exec sidekiq
```

How could I execute both processes?

Answer (score 0):

From the railway documentation:

> All you need to do is connect your GitHub account, create a new project, and then deploy your repo. We even support Procfiles out of the box. (Caveat: only a single process is supported for now) [0]

[0] - https://docs.railway.app/reference/compare-to-heroku#moving-from-heroku-to-railway

Looks like you would need multiple "projects" to invoke extra processes.